# Optimal drive configuration for SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, hardware

I have a fairly busy database server running SQL Server 2008 R2 that has the following setup:

- SATA RAID 1 (2 Drives)  - OS / Programs
- SAS  RAID 10 (4 Drives) - Sql Database Files (data and logs)
- SAS  RAID 1 (2 Drives)  - TempDB (data and logs)

Assuming I can't add additional drives into this server, have I made the best use of the configuration I have available? Or should I consider another scheme here where logs are isolated from the data files, for example?

**Update:**

For those that requested further hardware details:

- The SATA drives (used for the OS / Program partition) are: WD 7200 RPM 3 Gb/s 3.5 Inch SATA
- The SAS drives used in the other arrays are: Seagate 15K RPM 6 Gb/s 3.5 inch SAS
- The RAID controller used is an: LSI 9260-8i SAS/SATA 6 Gb 8 port

**Update 2:**

Based upon the feedback I've received, it looks like I have the following viable options to choose from - I will award the bounty to someone that can tell me which is *likely* to be the best in the environment that I've outlined:

1. Leave everything as is - I probably won't do much better
2. Move my 2 SAS RAID 1 drives into my existing RAID 10 array to have it composed
   of 6 disks in total
3. Move my log files onto the SAS RAID 1 and/or
   relocate TempDB (data or logs) back to the RAID 10

Comment: Your 2nd update is asking exactly the same questions as your original question, so the original answer applies. "...which is likely to be the best in the environment that I've outlined"... you haven't shown us any analysis of the workload, just that it is "fairly busy", so again the same answer applies.

Comment: With High-Performance NVMe and other SSD's disks in the market, The RAID is no longer very important from the [SQL server Disk Configuration Best Practices](http://www.faceofit.com/sql-server-disk-configuration-san-ssd-partitioning-best-practices/) perspective. Disk Pools (Storage Spaces) are the way to go forward. You would, however, need to logically separate the volumes in order to better troubleshoot disk related performance problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Variants of this question come up semi-regularly:

- [SQL Server build](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8573/sql-server-build)
- [Help me choose a RAID level combination for a SQL Server 2008 instance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7773/help-me-choose-a-raid-level-combination-for-a-sql-server-2008-instance)
- [How should I configure these disks on a SQL Server for a BI configuration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33440/how-should-i-configure-these-disks-on-a-sql-server-for-a-bi-configuration)

There are also occasional bun fights about the data/log separation "best practice".

- [Placing Transaction Log on Separate Volume [solid state]?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23049/2374)
- [SQL Server - Separating data, log, and TempDB files on a SAN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35404/sql-server-separating-data-log-and-tempdb-files-on-a-san/)

Without more detailed analysis of what this server is doing, the same advice applies as given previously.

- RAID 1 for OS
- RAID 10 (6 disk) for data/logs/tempdb

There is rarely any point in a split with so few spindles available. A single array with a larger IOPs capacity will typically soak up the lumps and bumps of your workload better than 2 smaller arrays.

One variant that can be worth testing is putting tempdb on the OS drive. Only do so if you have a representative workload that you can replay repeatedly, to ensure a fair comparison of the configuration. If you go for this arrangement in production make sure tempdb growth is restricted so you don't inadvertently consume all free space on the OS drive.

Given that your OS drives are 7200RPM coasters, I'd be surprised if the tempdb on OS drive config bore any benefit.

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on your workload, but with only 6 drives it does limit your options.  If your workload is not heavily dependent on tempdb for things such as sorts, hash tables, and snapshot isolation, then you might be better off using the 6 SAS drives together in RAID 10.  However, if you know or have the metrics to prove that tempdb is heavily utilized, then you should keep it separate as you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, changing the config of the ranges is (unfortunately) not an option as this server is in production. I am curious about switching the tempdb back to the RAID 10 and putting all log files on the RAID 1 though - is this a smart option?

Comment: Remember SQL Server needs to physically write all transactions to the log as part of the commit, so you want the fastest write performance possible within your config.  RAID 10 offers better write performance than RAID 1, so I would leave the logs on the faster volume.

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer depends on your needs but generally "put data and log on different arrays" is of higher importance than "put tempdb on its own array".

Given the number of drives you have available, my starting point would be:

1. Two drives, RAID 1 - Operating system, executables, pagefile.
2. Four drives, RAID 5 - All data files (alternatively, RAID 1+0)
3. Two drives, RAID 1 - All log files

What should do is use [SQLIO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20163) to test the performance of different drive configurations.

Comment: This definitely represents the "other side" of the advice I've read. I wish there was a definitive method to determine which of the options would be better without resorting to "trying it out" in a production environment.

Comment: SQLIOSim lets you try it out in preproduction because it does not require that SQL Server be already installed. Of course, you have to run it on the actual disks and arrays you want to compare.

Comment: And therein lies the issue - this server is already racked and in production, and I don't exactly have the budget to purchase equivalent gear to test these theories out on :)

Comment: @DanP Is it already running production data and supporting load? If not you can configure the drives as you wish and then test.. You should never go to production until you haven't tested all your options. I guess it wouldn't take more than a few days to do your tests. You would anyway want to save some days' worth of production load to be sure the new hardware can face the same stress conditions.

Comment: @Marian - yes, it is in production and supporting the load just fine right now. This isn't so much a question "out of necessity" as it is "out of interest" - I just want to get the most bang for the buck with my current gear, that's all.

Comment: @DanP Well, I personally would have gone with Mark's advice and chose a RAID10 with the rest of the drives (except OS). Log files are write intensive and need better performance than what RAID 1 has to offer, as far as I think of it. But I'm not a hardware expert. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I should mention that my opinion comes only from the experience of a past (kind of) failed migration to a better server, but with worse performance. We never tested a real load on this new server, we never had a chance, the server was not ready on time. Turns out the server testing BEFORE migrating to production should be MANDATORY. Sorry for the emphasis. So my mantra for all migrations/upgrades is: TEST, TEST, TEST,... freaking test as much as possible.

Comment: Not sure whether to start with RAID 5 or SQLIOSIM... let's go with the later as the former speaks for itself. SQLIOSIM is a [correctness and stress test tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/beatrice/archive/2007/04/20/sqliosim-for-dummies.aspx), it is not a performance or load testing tool. It has absolutely no place in comparing the performance of config-X vs config-Y for workload-Z. All that would tell you is how well config-X performs against config-Y in a SQLIOSIM run. If you want to compare the performance for workload-Z, test workload-Z.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I forgot about that. For benchmarking purposes you need [SQLIO](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/09/finding-your-san-bottlenecks-with-sqlio/), [not SQLIOSIM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/04/05/sqliosim-is-not-an-i-o-performance-tuning-tool.aspx).

Comment: Marian, if you want log performance then RAID1 *is* what you pick. RAID1 is faster for writing than RAID1+0.

Comment: Thanks for comments about SQLIO vs SQLIOSim. My bad for typing the wrong one in my answer. I'm not sure that's worth all the downvotes, however…

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker "RAID1 is faster for writing than RAID1+0" is nonsense. Where did this idea come from?

Comment: The idea comes from this forum not allowing edits for more than 5 minutes. I was in another web browser sessions finding interesting links about SQLIO and my comment timed out before I could fix my typo. Anyway, with that excuse out of the way, RAID 1+0 is faster than RAID 1, true, but given the original poster's post, RAID 1+0 was not possible, which is why I said "RAID1 is what you pick".

Comment: And with that edit now in place, what exactly is SQLIO going to prove for the OP? My earlier comment applies equally if you replace SQLIOSIM for SQLIO.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker As I said, in current case I would have not chosen a separate RAID 1, but the bigger 6 disks RAID 1+0 and put the files altogether. My gut feeling would be even in this case the log would still have better place there. But I would've tested before putting the disks in production, because benchmarking is fun, not only necessary :-).

Answer (score 2):

*It very much depends on what you mean by "very busy": different workload patterns (write heavy or not, bulk operations common or not, level of concurrent access, to name but three of the many variables) can have a drastic effect on the performance of any given spindle arrangement.*

For a write heavy situation separating the logs from the data can make a significant difference as each write involves updating both the log and the data files, so involves a fair amount of extra head flipping if both sets of files are on the same set of spindles.

Without further reference to your workload (and the spec of those drives and any controller that is between them and the machine) I'd be inclined to go for three volumes: one for OS+programs and tempdb (data), one for main DB data, and the third for logs (both tempdb and main DBs).

Of course if your workloads are all very light on write operations then you shouldn't spend too much time worrying about keeping data and logs separate, as it'll make little performance difference and dedicating a whole volume for them would be quite wasteful of available space.

Comment: I would certainly describe our environment as a "heavy write" one - I will update my question with more detailed hardware specs on Monday.

Comment: Any idea about the number of drives that OP has? I'm thinking more of the Raid 1 that he has for the log files. That doesn't sound like a great option for write purposes, and AFAIK log files are not read limited, but write..

Comment: I have added additional specs about the hardware of the machine.

Comment: This misunderstanding may be at the root of many of the data/log separation rants, so apologies but I'm going to call it out. "...as each write involves updating both the log and the data files" - no, it does not. Writes to data pages occur on checkpoint, not on every modification.

Comment: @Mark: Happy to stand corrected on the specifics, but depending on your recovery model checkpoints are very regular and at the checkpoint there is still I/O to both areas. I can't find the results now but a couple of years ago we ran benchmarks on a couple of long-running write heavy processes that one of our clients run regularly and physically separating the data and logs made a noticeable difference. Of course that is a very specific example so won't apply everywhere and even where is does the convenience of not having a separate log volume may trump a small performance gain. YMMV.

Comment: @DavidSpillett True, there will always be cases where the split is beneficial. The key is that you tested and validated that the configuration was beneficial for that particular workload.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you are using the DB for (OLTP vs warehousing) your config looks like a good general config.  If you had more disks, you would have more options.

You could get better performance if you switched the disk for your TempDB to RAID 0 (stripe).  It increases your risk for failure, but since TempDB only buffers data, you can't experience data loss. So most people consider that a reasonable trade-off.  Just keep a spare around (or a hot-spare).

One thing you didn't mention, but could try (if you haven't already): Microsoft recommends splitting your TempDB up over several files (one per CPU).  Of course, it is best if they are on separate disks, but simply having separate files helps.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Tempdb is used for many things, but don't treat it as a throwaway database and place it on a RAID 0.  Keep in mind if that RAID 0 volume fails, SQL Server will not be able to start up.

Comment: I have indeed created one temp db per core as suggested, but thanks for raising that point as well :)

Comment: Well these suggestions are not very good and are not appropriate for every environment. First one is mentioned by @PatrickKeisler earlier. The second is a myth that Paul Randal debunked some time ago. The article is this one: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (12/30) tempdb should always have one data file per processor core](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-1230-tempdb-should-always-have-one-data-file-per-processor-core/). So MS documentation can be wrong, don't take it by heart.

Comment: "since TempDB only buffers data, you can't experience data loss"... and I'm sure the users of the system will appreciate that during the X hours of downtime they suffer while a) ops dig around in the basement for a replacement disk or b) a DBA tries to explain to the helpdesk how to move tempdb, from his mobile phone.